# Solr as complete solution?

Tags: java, solr, web-crawler

I was thinking of using [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) for a crawl engine. I need to store 1 billion URLS in a database, with metadata such as "title", "description" etc, as well as the links between each URL. The problems:

- the crawl logic MUST be written in java (i.e. Nutch isn't an option)
- mysql is too slow for searching purposes when it comes to 2 billion rows
- i'm pretty sure i'm going to re-invent the wheel by not using solr

My goal is to be able to map the links between URLs on the internet. While probably a small protion at first, it might become more and when it does, I want to be prepared for scaling now. So my biggest fear will only come in a month or two's time, but I need to know my ability to quickly get a list of all links between URLs is crucial whether there are 1 million rows, or 1 billion. Which is why I need to know upfront how possible this will be.

1. Does SOLR act as a buffer between MySQL and the User? So effectively, SOLR is a seperate database that indexes MySQL. Then users actually search SOLR? And I assume the database that SOLR stores to is its own internal database?
2. Will SOLR allow me to expand storage across multiple servers? What about processing?
3. Can SOLR allow me to see all URLs linking to other URLs. I.e. Store a reference to all other links that link to any other URL in the DB?

Comment: I worked on the subject a while ago and cannot say much, but I strongly recommend researching solr with MongoDB instead of mySql

Comment: Can you perhaps tell me if you know if solr with mongodb will be able to map a relation between each url? And quickly?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be quick enough for you, but I can guarantee that it will be better than mysql.

Comment: (1) Why use Mongo at all? I'd say Solr alone is enough for your purpose. (2) You can easily expand storage and processing via SolrCloud. (3) You can certainly do that - you would first create all your documents in the index, with blank reference fields, then have a second phase that adds the links between documents in your index.

Comment: Do you know if I will be able to match URLs and say, for example, URL A appears X times on URL B? Or more importantly, that URL A has Y incoming links from such and such site?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at Hadoop (https://hadoop.apache.org/). You could capture your web data in any format, then write map-reduce functions to analyse the data. It's certainly scalable to any size you need and you can keep your code to 100% Java. I used Hadoop a few years ago at a hackathon to do an analysis of the Twitter social graph to see how closely related different communities are. What you're planning sounds similar.